# Contact number stays nil

Tags: ios, tableview, addressbook, null

I have an mutableArray and put the number of a contact in it.

I use the following code:

```
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = (ABMultiValueRef)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
CFRelease(phoneNumbers);
number = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);


[thenumbers addObject:number];
```

In order to retrieve it, I do this:

```
Contacts *num = [thenumbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *numbers = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [num number]];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = numbers;
```

I set breakpoints and it stops at the right lines. I also tried

```
NSLog(@"%@", number);
```

And it returns the numbers. And yes I have reloadDate in viewWillappear.

Comment: If you radically edit your question after you've received answers, the answers don't make any sense. Which makes the question and answers of limited use to anyone else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're releasing `phoneNumbers` straight after copying to it. Try moving it to after you use it.

Or, better still, transfer the ownership to the NSString object through ARC

```
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = (ABMultiValueRef)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
number = (__bridge_transfer NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);
```

And there is no need to call `CFRelease(phoneNumbers)` at all.

As for getting the numbers into the cell, you're getting confused about your types. You're putting an `NSString` into `theNumber` but your pulling out a `Contacts`. And then sending it some kind of `number` message.

You've put a string in the array, you can only pull out a string or a subclass.

```
NSString *numbers = [thenumbers objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.detailTextLabel.text = numbers;
```

Comment: Thanks I did that. Weirdly it still is (null) in the tableView.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. But now it won't return anything. Not (null) nor the number. Checked with NSLog and breakpoints again and the numbers are definitely in the array.

Comment: There's not a lot I can do without seeing the rest of the code.

Comment: I edited it and added the code that is used in order to get the number and display it.

Comment: Editing it makes my answer and the other answer completely pointless. I've rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 1):

In the following code,

```
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = (ABMultiValueRef)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
CFRelease(phoneNumbers);
number = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);
```

You are releasing the `phoneNumbers` and then you are accesing the variable. Change it to as follows.

```
ABMultiValueRef phoneNumbers = (ABMultiValueRef)ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty);
number = (__bridge NSString*)ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(phoneNumbers, 0);
CFRelease(phoneNumbers);
```

Comment: Thank you, but I went with Abizerns solution. Its kinda the same I guess. But the tableView still returns (Null) and not the number.